# SQL statement using WHERE from a GROUP or RANK

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause, ranking

I have a sales snapshot with about *35,000 rows*. Let's call the columns:

```
Sales Rep | Account ID | Total Contract Value | Date
```

I need to group everything by `Sales Rep` and then from there, select that `Sales Rep`'s **top 35 accounts based off of `Total Contract Value` where the `Total Contract Value` is >= $10,000 for the Month (Date) of January 2013**.

So for example, say John Doe had 294 accounts in this table from January, I only want to see his top 35 accounts >= $10,000 , same for Jane Doe, etc. etc. It's very important that the query be as efficient in it's resource usage as possible.

Thoughts?

Comment: What kind of database do you have? MS Sql Server, MySql, Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you want to use a function called `row_number()`:

```
select ss.*
from (select ss.*, row_number() over (partition by salesrep order by ContractValue desc) as seqnum
      from snapshot ss
      where TotalContractValue >= 10000 and date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31'
     ) ss
where seqnum <= 35
```

You don't specify the database you are using.  In databases that don't have `row_number()`, there are alternatives that are less efficient.

Comment: So here's another question. Let's say I have another column, ParentAccountID. How would you change this query to select an agents top 35 parent account IDs (which would include multiple Account IDs) based off of TCV. So essentially you group by agent and then from that you take all the information for the top 35 parent account IDs where their grouped parent account IDs TCV is greater than 10,000. Make sense?

Comment: One more addition, in the final output, there would be more than 35 line items per agent b/c it'd be based off of my top 35 Parent_Account_IDs but each line item represents an actual accountID. So say I might have 2 accounts under Parent account ID ABC2 and that parent's ranking will be 1 b/c the combined parent account IDs TCV is say $150,000, 4 rows for the accounts under parent Account ID ABC4 and that ranking is 2 b/c it's TCV is say $100,000, etc. etc.

Comment: @Joshua . . . Can you ask another question incorporating this additional information in?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is already in your title, partition by `SalesRep` and `AccountID` and Rank by `Total Contact Value`.

A `SQL Server` solution will look like:

```
DECLARE @minimumValue decimal(20,2) = 10000
DECLARE @numberOfAccounts int = 35
DECLARE @from datetime = '1/1/2013'
DECLARE @till datetime = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @from)

SELECT 
  [sub].[Sales Rep],
  [sub].[Rank],
  [sub].[Account ID],
  [sub].[Total Contract Value]
FROM
(
  SELECT
    [Sales Rep],
    [Account ID],
    [Total Contract Value],
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Sales Rep] ORDER BY [Total Contract Value] DESC) AS [Rank]
  FROM [Sales]
  WHERE
    [Total Contract Value] >= @minimumValue
    AND [Date] > @from
    AND [Date] < @till
) AS [sub]
WHERE [sub].[Rank] <= @numberOfAccounts
ORDER BY 
  [Sales Rep] ASC,
  [Rank] ASC
```

Here is a (simple) [Sql Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/106e4/3).

Comment: Excellent Jacco. Thank you. I'm still kind of green in SQL but that did the trick.

Comment: Glad to help you out. And keep coming back to SO!

Comment: Hi Jacco, posing this question to you too: So here's another question. Let's say I have another column, ParentAccountID. How would you change this query to select an agents top 35 parent account IDs (which would include multiple Account IDs) based off of TCV. So essentially you group by agent and then from that you take all the information for the top 35 parent account IDs where their grouped parent account IDs TCV is greater than 10,000. Make sense?