# SQL statement using WHERE from a GROUP or RANK (part 2)

Tags: sql, sum, grouping, where-clause

I recently posted a question about a SQL Where Statement/Grouping here:

[SQL statement using WHERE from a GROUP or RANK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654855/sql-statement-using-where-from-a-group-or-rank)

Now I've got somewhat of a follow-up.

So similar to the previous question, let's assume I have a table of say 35,000 rows with these columns:

Sales Rep | Parent Account ID| Account ID | Total Contract Value | Date

Each row is individual by account id but multiple account IDs can fall under a parent account ID.

Similar to the responses on the first question, this is probably going to be a table w/i a table. So first, everything has to be grouped by Sales Rep. From that, everything needs to be grouped by Parent Account ID where the grouped total contract value of all the accounts is >= 10,000. Then everything will be displayed and ranked by the total TCV of the Parent account ID and I need the top 35 Parent account IDs by agent.

So the first couple of lines of data may look like this:

```
Sales Rep | Parent Account ID| Account ID | Total Contract Value | Date      | Rank
John Doe  | ParentABC12345   | ABC425     | 5,000                | 1/2/2013  |1
John Doe  | ParentABC12345   | ABC426     | 10,000               | 1/2/2013  |1
John Doe  | ParentDJE12345   | DJE523     | 11,000               | 1/2/2013  |2
John Doe  | ParentFBC12345   | FBC6723    | 4,000                | 1/2/2013  |3
John Doe  | ParentFBC12345   | FBC6727    | 4,000                | 1/2/2013  |3
```

Notice how the ranking works based off of the parent Account ID. The account ID DJE523 has the single greatest TCV but it's ranked second b/c the grouped value of parent account ID ParentABC12345 is greater. So there would be a ranking of 35 parent account IDs but in that ranking their could be say 100+ lines of actual data.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @Joshua....which DB tool are you using.  SQL Server, Oracle, etc?

Comment: @Joshua, I improved my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always nice to follow up. The "parent rank" is added as an `INNER JOIN`.

*Edit*: As correctly mentioned by Dan Bracuk, [my first answer](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62967/1) was not correct. I altered the query to meet the correct conditions. I also applied the timespan to the Parent Account's.

```
DECLARE @minimumValue decimal(20,2) = 10000
DECLARE @numberOfAccounts int = 35
DECLARE @from datetime = '1/1/2013'
DECLARE @till datetime = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @from)

SELECT 
  [sub].[Sales Rep],
  [sub].[Rank],
  [sub].[Account ID],
  [sub].[Total Contract Value],
  [sub].[Parent Account ID],
  [sub].[Total],
  [sub].[ParentRank]
FROM
(
  SELECT
    [s].[Sales Rep],
    [s].[Account ID],
    [s].[Total Contract Value],
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [s].[Sales Rep] ORDER BY [s].[Total Contract Value] DESC) AS [Rank],
    [p].[Parent Account ID],
    [p].[Total],
    [p].[ParentRank]
  FROM [Sales] [s]
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT
      [Parent Account ID],
      SUM([Total Contract Value]) AS [Total],
      RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUM([Total Contract Value]) DESC) AS [ParentRank]
    FROM [Sales]
    WHERE[Date] > @from AND [Date] < @till
    GROUP BY [Parent Account ID]
    HAVING SUM([Total Contract Value]) > @minimumValue
  ) AS [p] ON [s].[Parent Account ID] = [p].[Parent Account ID]
  WHERE [Date] > @from AND [Date] < @till
) AS [sub]
WHERE [sub].[Rank] <= @numberOfAccounts
ORDER BY 
  [Sales Rep] ASC,
  [ParentRank] ASC,
  [Rank] ASC
```

[And here is a new Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3331/2).

Comment: Well, I actually still don't know... But he is referring to a previous question, on which he did like my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14654951/410699

Comment: One of us is missing something.  The question says, "grouped total contract value of all the accounts is >= 10,000" but this answer appears to have the logic of individual sales >= 10000.

Comment: Ooops, my bad. That criteria should then move from the WHERE to a new HAVING clause on the Parent Account's then. Not in a position though to correct my answer. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @DanBracuk I improved my answer.

Comment: Hi Jacco, sorry, I've been traveling quite a bit lately and haven't had time to get back to this but I really appreciate the help. So You're saying I need to place a having clause in? Which part of the query would that come in?

Answer (score -1):

I think this will do it for you, if you're using SQL Server:

```
Select top 35 
    SalesRep, 
    ParentAccountId, 
    sum(TotalContractValue)  from Table
group by SalesRep, ParentAccountId 
order by sum(TotalContractValue) desc
```

Comment: -1 Apart from missing a "from"-clause, this does not even come near a solution to the question asked.

Comment: Fair enough! The question is to select a maximum of 35 Accounts, for each single SalesRep (so with 10 SalesReps, max 350 Accounts). These have to be sorted by the sum of the total contract value of there ParentAccounts and then by their own total contract value. 
The answer only lists a total maximum of 35 (non-unique) SalesReps, with their ParentAccountId, sorted by sum of the total contract value of this ParentAccountId scored by this SalesRep (so not the total value of the ParentAccount). 
In my opinion this makes a huge gap between question and answer.