# Using a where statement with rank and a subquery in SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, where-clause

so I have a table that's sort of like this:

| DELIVERY_AREA_ID | DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS | EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 234sfd | 4000 | 2020-01-01 12:19:29.719 |
| 234sfd | 6500 | 2020-01-01 12:31:40.325 |
| 234sfd | 3500 | 2020-01-01 12:53:10.538 |
| 234sfd | 6500 | 2020-01-01 13:11:36.094 |
| 234sfd | 3500 | 2020-01-01 13:32:26.754 |
| 234sfd | 6500 | 2020-01-01 13:59:11.104 |
| 234sfd | 6500 | 2020-01-02 07:44:16.792 |
| 234sfd | 3500 | 2020-01-02 08:07:36.284 |
| 234sfd | 6500 | 2020-01-02 08:54:08.014 |
| 234sfd | 3500 | 2020-01-02 09:53:05.853 |
| 234sfd | 6500 | 2020-01-02 10:04:39.443 |
| 234sfd | 10000 | 2020-07-01 08:29:20.194 |
| 234sfd | 3500 | 2020-07-03 07:50:41.782 |
| 234sfd | 10000 | 2020-07-03 08:33:14.695 |
| 234sfd | 3500 | 2020-07-05 07:47:05.539 |
| 234sfd | 10000 | 2020-07-05 07:53:13.930 |
| 234sfd | 3500 | 2020-07-05 09:18:57.688 |
| 234sfd | 10000 | 2020-07-05 09:51:07.547 |
| 234sfd | 3500 | 2020-07-19 18:02:14.099 |

the data is actually much more varied but yeah it follows that format.

I am trying to, in one query, in snowflake database, make a get the top ranked radius by duration. I currently have this:

```
SELECT DELIVERY_AREA_ID,
       MAX(DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS) AS default_delivery_radius,
       MONTH_YEAR,
       DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS,
       SUM(DURATION_SECONDS) AS total_duration,
       MAX(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) AS MAX_TIMESTAMP,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID, MONTH_YEAR
                    ORDER BY SUM(DURATION_SECONDS) DESC) AS RADIUS_RANK
FROM (
    -- Add the MONTH_YEAR column to the delivery_radius_log table
    SELECT DELIVERY_AREA_ID,
           DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS,
           EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP,
           CONCAT(MONTH(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP), '/',
                  YEAR(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS MONTH_YEAR,
           DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)), EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) AS end_timestamp,
           DATEDIFF(second, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS duration_seconds
    FROM delivery_radius_log
) t  -- added alias here
GROUP BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID, MONTH_YEAR, DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS
```

I want to get the first rank for each month_year but when I use

```
where RADIUS_RANK = 1
```

I get an error: Syntax error: unexpected 'where'. (line 21)

Im not sure how to resolve this

I have tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654855/sql-statement-using-where-from-a-group-or-rank) which appears to have the same question but the solution is already what I am trying.

Comment: can you use `ORDER BY SUM(DURATION_SECONDS)` ? can you use `GROUP BY ` and `RANK()` in same select? Is it possible to split the logic. To get `to get the first rank for each month_year ` we can use a simple logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to solve this scenario without querying the output of your query, in other words, using the output of that query as an input for another top-level query.

- You can not use a field produced at the projection level in the WHERE clause
- You can not use analytic functions in the WHERE clause
- You can not use analytic functions in a HAVING clause

So the only solution is to query the output of that query and retrieve only the MIN rank.

Comment: so I could possibly start off using a 'WITH' statement to build one query, probably the one I have set up, then a second query that would retrieve the min rank?

Comment: You can use CTEs, views or build a more complex query, that is up to you and of course depends on your use case

Answer (score 0):

To filter windowed function at the same query level you need to use [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) clause:

```
SELECT DELIVERY_AREA_ID,
       MAX(DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS) AS default_delivery_radius,
       MONTH_YEAR,
       DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS,
       SUM(DURATION_SECONDS) AS total_duration,
       MAX(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) AS MAX_TIMESTAMP,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID, MONTH_YEAR
                    ORDER BY SUM(DURATION_SECONDS) DESC) AS RADIUS_RANK
FROM (
    -- Add the MONTH_YEAR column to the delivery_radius_log table
    SELECT DELIVERY_AREA_ID,
           DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS,
           EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP,
           CONCAT(MONTH(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP), '/',
                  YEAR(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS MONTH_YEAR,
           DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)), EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) AS end_timestamp,
           DATEDIFF(second, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS duration_seconds
    FROM delivery_radius_log
) t  -- added alias here
GROUP BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID, MONTH_YEAR, DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS
QUALIFY RADIUS_RANK = 1;
```

If the rank column is not required then the entire expression could be moved:

```
SELECT DELIVERY_AREA_ID,
       MAX(DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS) AS default_delivery_radius,
       MONTH_YEAR,
       DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS,
       SUM(DURATION_SECONDS) AS total_duration,
       MAX(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) AS MAX_TIMESTAMP
FROM (
    -- Add the MONTH_YEAR column to the delivery_radius_log table
    SELECT DELIVERY_AREA_ID,
           DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS,
           EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP,
           CONCAT(MONTH(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP), '/',
                  YEAR(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS MONTH_YEAR,
           DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)), EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) AS end_timestamp,
           DATEDIFF(second, EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LEAD(EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID ORDER BY EVENT_STARTED_TIMESTAMP)) AS duration_seconds
    FROM delivery_radius_log
) t  -- added alias here
GROUP BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID, MONTH_YEAR, DELIVERY_RADIUS_METERS
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DELIVERY_AREA_ID, MONTH_YEAR
                    ORDER BY SUM(DURATION_SECONDS) DESC) = 1;
```